# Как создать локальный реф из vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue3

С бэка прилетает пользователь с заполненным телефоном или нет.
пользователя я сохраняю в vuex.
в родительском компоненте формы я получаю номер телефона при помощи computed.

```
const phone = computed(() => userModule.state.user.phone)
```

дальше передаю в дочерний компонент инпута

```
app-phone-input(
    :model-value="phone"
    @update:model-value="phoneHandler"
)
```

получаю в дочернем компоненте

```
el-input(
    v-model="phone"
)

props: {
            modelValue: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
        },
        emits: ['update:modelValue'],

        setup(props, { emit }) {
            return {
                phone: computed({
                    get: () => props.modelValue,
                    set: (value) =>
                        emit('update:modelValue', value),
                }),
            }
        }
```

таким образом я получаю в консоли computed только для чтения и его нельзя изменять.
и вопрос как мне создать локальный реф в родительском компоненте, что бы не изменять его в vuex.
заранее спасибо.

Comment: Самое очевидное `setup() { const store = useStore(); const phone = ref(store.state.user.phone); /*...*/ }` - не работает?

Comment: нет получаю undefined.
это я так понял из за асинхронности, сначала объект пуст, только после ответа сервера я получаю данные и ref не реагирует.

Comment: А, теперь понятно, компонент строится до получения ответа сервера... Хм. Тут по идее напрашивается `store.subscribe` для обновления локального рефа по совершении мутации - не пробовал так?

Comment: не только не пробовал, но и впервые слышу о `store.subscribe` пойду гляну что это. спасибо за наводку.

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Суть варианта решения: в компоненте создаешь реф и подписываешься на мутации; в коллбэке `subscribe` проверяешь `mutation.type` - если совпадает, то меняешь значение рефа на `mutation.payload` (или его свойство, если в пэйлоаде объект); ну и при разрушении компонента (или сразу после первой подходящей мутации, по желанию) отписываешься. Доки тут: https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe